# Adding a white space within a filename using Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a very large repository of .txt documents with the same naming scheme.  I would like to write a simple Python script to add a space at a particular point in the filename.

Current Name Scheme:

John -Doe0001.txt

John -Doe0002.txt

John -Doe0003.txt

John -Doe0004.txt

Expected Outcome After Python Script:

John - Doe0001.txt

John - Doe0002.txt

John - Doe0003.txt

John - Doe0004.txt

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, this will replace the dash with a dash and whitespace. Its basic but it works :)

`textfile = "John -Doe0001.txt"
textfile = textfile.replace('-','- ')
x = open(textfile, 'w')`